# Java and @JsonProperty

Tags: java, jackson

I am wondering if there is a way to apply @JsonProperty to an inherited fields of a class.
For example I have the following classes.

```
public class Person {
    protected String id;
    protected String firstName;
    protected String middleName;
    protected String lastName;
}

...

/**
 * need to figure out here, how to apply @JsonProperty
 * to the fields below of the parent class:
 * protected String id;
 * protected String firstName;
 * protected String middleName;
 * protected String lastName;
 */
public class Employee extends Person {
   @JsonProperty("DepartmentID")
   protected String departmentId;
}
```

the goal here is that only Employee class will have @JsonProperty not the Person class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Override getter methods with @JsonProperty

```
   @JsonProperty("DepartmentID")
   protected String departmentId;
   @Override
   @JsonProperty("id")
   public String getId(){
     return super.getId();
   }
 // other getter methods
}
```

Comment: you basically have the same answer with Zeke. But question... what happens to the setter? e.g. can I use "DepartmentID" as setter in the Json?

Answer (score 2):

Use getters and setters and annotate your getter instead of the field. Jackson will automatically detect the setter based on the getter name.

```java
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

   .. etc ...
}

public class Employee extends Person {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    ... etc ...
}
```

Comment: great! Thanks for this. But question, what happens to the setter? or this implementation includes the setter also?

Comment: In my experience if you put the annotation on the getter Jackson figures out the setter automatically. I haven’t tried it but I assume if the setter is in the extended class it would find it. Either way, jackson does require a setter